# Anatomy of Knee Locking That Heals in Weeks

Tags: knee, legs, tear-of-a-meniscus

I am trying to understand the anatomy of my injury.

**How it happened:** I was cutting to the left in basketball. My right knee popped 3 times and I felt sharp pain. Immediately after the injury I couldn't extend my leg any more.

**Extension:** I can extend it to about 20-30 deg from straight. After that I get a sharp pain in anterior-medial below the patella (where the meniscus is).

**Flexion:** After the injury I could flex it almost all the way. Two days after it locks 45 degrees from fully bent. At that point I get a sharp pain in posterior-lateral region of the knee (in the knee crevice).

**General:** I can put moderete weight on my leg, but can't walk without crutches because I cannot straighten it.

**History:** I had the exact same injury (simptoms) 2 times in my life before. Each time, I would stay in bed 2-3 weeks and could limp. A month or two and I could walk/run. I also had an ACL surgery 8 months ago (after those two times).

**Question:** I can't understand why my knee locks. The general belief is that a part of meniscus is stuck underneath the knee and this is in line with my immediate locking. However, I feel like it doesn't explain why I am able to region the range of motion 2-3 weeks after the injury. Is there any other explanation?

Comment: These are very good questions that you should ask your doctor. On Health.SE, they are considered off-topic because we can't see you and we can't examine you. This does not mean that this effort is wasteful: **Bring a printed version of your questions to the appointment**, this way, you will not forget any important aspects you wanted to know about. Usually, doctors always like it when someone has a sound interest into their own health, and also an interest into the doctor's work.

Comment: Excellently said, @Narusan.  I would consider seeing an Orthopedic specialist if you're able to due to the complexities of locking issues.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will be seeing a specialist tomorrow. However, I am curious on how to pose a medical question so that it isn't considered offtopic? Should I rewrite it like it doesn't apply to me (e.g. in 3rd person)? Should I rewrite it so that it doesn't apply to anyone (e.g. in passive form)?

Comment: @Mirko Not sure I should recommend it or not, but that's what I do. And I'll usually leave questions open that are worded that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **As I can't see you in person.  This is by no means a Dx, please see a physician or physical therapist as soon as possible.  They will be
>   able to perform an evaluation to determine the extent of the injury**

---

### You cannot treat this yourself you MUST see a specialist.

---

***This is only an idea of what may be going on, I cannot tell without an eval.***

- https://flexcin.com/6-telltale-signs-your-knee-injury-is-serious/
- https://www.coreconcepts.com.sg/condition/the-buckling-knee/

[image]
[image]